# cordova platform add android new error

Tags: android, cordova

I hit the following error while executing `cordova platform add android`:

```
c:\users\demolition hammer\hellox> cordova platform add android

creating android project...
C:\users\demolition' is not recognised as an internal or extrenal command, operable program or batch file
error: c:\users\demoliton hammer\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.
bat:command failed with exit code 1
    at childprocess.whendone <c:\users\demolition hammer\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:126:23>
    at childprocess.eventemitter.emit <events.js:98:17>
    at maybeclose <child_process.js:743:16>
    at process.childprocess._handle.oneexit <child_process.js:810:5>
```

I accidentally deleted the default path of the environment system variable. I have entered a default path for my PC. Apart from that, other paths should be fine. Kindly help me out. This is very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a well known problem with the Cordova CLI is that it does not support spaces in the path. Sometimes. In some commands, the path string is properly sanitized. In others, not so much.

Create/Move your project to a directory with alphanumeric characters only and it should work fine.

You could also use the PhoneGap CLI, which has parallel core functionality, but also allows you to upload to PhoneGap build. It handles paths with spaces properly. If it doesn't, I can fix it as I'm the primary maintainer :P

Comment: For me (and related to what Lorenzo is saying) it was an Ampersand in the display name, found in config.xml